# Slow Performance When Reading Excel With Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, performance

When reading from excel with `Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel` and using `Range dataRange = (Range)cSheet.Cells[row, col];` the performance is very slow. When I Remove `Range dataRange = (Range)cSheet.Cells[row, col];` it is faster. What did I miss. What should I change ?

```
int rows = cSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int cols = cSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

for (int row = 2; row <= rows; row++)
{
  for (int col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
  {
        Range dataRange = (Range)cSheet.Cells[row, col];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do it in one operation:

```
object[,] objectArray = cSheet.get_Range("A1:C4").Value2;
dataRange.Value2 = objectArray;
```

To get the UsedRange address for "A1:C4", try:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = cSheet.UsedRange;
string address = range.get_Address();
string[] cells = address.Split(new char[] {':'});
string beginCell = cells[0].Replace("$", "");
string endCell = cells[1].Replace("$", "");
```

Comment: In what way to set the values ? I am using it like this but this is slow object value = objectArray[row, col];
                                                        ((Range)jetixSheet.Cells[row, col]).Value2 = value;

Comment: Yes you're iterating through all the rows and cols to get the values, whereas I've shown you a way to assign all values to a multi-dimension object array in one line of code: `dataRange.Value2 = objectArray;`

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have question related to this answer, can you help?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49784560/1462656