# How to copy contents of Excel UsedRange into an array for faster reading?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to improve the performance of an application that is reading cells from an Excel worksheet row by row.  I found this solution

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842904/1462656
>
> You want to do it in one operation:

```
object[,] objectArray = cSheet.get_Range("A1:C4").Value2; 
dataRange.Value2 = objectArray;
```

Is it assuming all the cells are of type Value2?.

In general I would like to know how to get the contents of the UsedRange into a local array for faster access (instead of keep going back and forth through the interop).  But I don't know in advance the size, but I know in advance the cell types on each column.  They are a combination of Value2 and Formula.

My code so far

```
        Application application = new Application();
        application.Workbooks.Open(file);
        Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.get_Item(1);
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        Range UsedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        int rows = UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int cols = UsedRange.Columns.Count;

        object[,] objectArray = new object[rows,cols];
```

I don't know what to do next.

I was going to do this

```
objectArray = (object[,])UsedRange.Range[?,?];
```

But I don't know the syntax to specify the Range using the columns count and rows count I found above.

Originally I had a for loop like this which was extremely slow

```
for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex < UsedRange.Rows.Count; rowIndex++){

    string str1= UsedRange.Rows.Cells[rowIndex, 0 + 1].Value2.ToString();
    string str2= UsedRange.Rows.Cells[rowIndex, 1 + 1].Formula as string;

}
```

Comment: Why not ask op of answer 1? He is active on SO and might help you better..

Comment: did you try `object[,] objectArray = worksheet.get_Range($"A1:{cols}{rows}").Value2;` ?

Comment: @Michael I think some of the cells are Formula, not all Value2....How do I do it without having to specify in advance that they are all Value2

Comment: `But I don't understand the first two lines of code of the first post.` You would be best to include all of the relevant code in **this** post - people are less likely to click links and read content from elsewhere. Each question should be as standalone as possible.

Comment: Try `cSheet.get_Range("A1:C4").Formula`.  AFAIK this will return an array of strings which may be a formula or a cell value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not specify the range as cell values as in the other solutions for example

```
shtName.get_Range("A1:Z100")
```

So what I was missing was a way to specify the used range without entering cell range as above, and I found the answer from this example

https://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet

```
        Range UsedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

        object[,] objectArray = (object[,])UsedRange.Value[XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault];

        for (int row = 2; row < objectArray.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        {
             string str1= (objectArray[row, 1] == null) ? string.Empty : objectArray[row, 1].ToString();

             string str2= (objectArray[row, 2] == null) ? string.Empty : objectArray[row, 2].ToString();

             //...etc
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is to do the Excel operation in one step and then use the .Net `object[,]`. Eg:

```
object[,] objectArray = new object[rows,cols];
```

> I don't know what to do next.

```
object[,] objectArray = shtName.get_Range("A1:Z100").Value2;

for (int row = 0; row < objectArray.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < objectArray.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(objectArray[row,col].ToString());
    }
}
```

<sub>ps I haven't tested this, very busy today</sub>

Each time you call Excel there is an underlying RPC call that gets marshalled.

This will help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983731/495455

Comment: ok thanks for replying, this approach works however what I was really looking for is UsedRange.Value[XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault], see the answer I added.